# Get Average and Join 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables which are given below;

User table:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>uid</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>status</td>
<td>category</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Jane Doe</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>C</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Profile Table:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>pid</td>
<td>uid</td>
<td>slug</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>john-doe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>jane-doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And Rating Table:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>rid</td>
<td>uid</td>
<td>rating</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>3.5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2.5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3.5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2.5</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3.5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2.5</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>3.5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2.5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I m trying to join the table and get value having common id with avg rating from rating fromr rating table.

the output I want is given below;

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>uid</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>slug</td>
<td>status</td>
<td>category</td>
<td>rating</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>john-doe</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>C</td>
<td>3.25</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Jane Doe</td>
<td>jane-doe</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>C</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below query, I think this will work for you.

> select u.*, p.slug, (select avg(rating) from Rating r where r.uid=u.uid) as rating from User u JOIN Profile p ON p.uid=u.uid